# Double click in List Box to open another form on a specific record

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I've set up a DblClick function on a list box so that on double clicking a row, it will open another form (with its own list box), filtering on a specific record from the row clicked on.

However, I'm getting a

> Run-Time error '3075': Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression '[fieldname] = '.

(Where field name is the bound column to be filtered on).

Here is my dblclick code:

```
Private Sub ListBoxname_DblClick(Cancel As Integer)
Dim RecordId As Integer
DoCmd.OpenForm "newformname", acNormal, , "[fieldname] = " & Me.ListBoxname.Column(2)
Forms("newformname").Requery
End Sub
```

I've also set up the new form properties (Data tab) to filter on the fieldname as fieldname=

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently `Me.ListBoxname.Column(2)` returns NULL.

If your key is in the **second** column, you need to use `Me.ListBoxname.Column(1)`, because the column list is zero-based.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/access-vba/articles/listbox-column-property-access

Note: you don't need `Forms("newformname").Requery` after opening it.

Comment: Thank you. This has stopped the error appearing BUT now a parameter window comes up for the [fieldname] which I don't want. I want it to use the [fieldname] as a value to connect and filter on another form that will open up on the double click. How do I do this?

Comment: Then you have either a spelling error or `[fieldname]` isn't in the recordsource of the 2nd form. Please edit your question with your actual code.